# How to add the android application as a library to another android application?

Tags: android

i create one simple apps.here i want use the one already create apps (name : mainLabProject) in my current apps.so i make the mainLabProject as library.goto `project explorer`->right click the `project Name`-> select `Properties`->select `android` then ->select `isLibrary` click `true` and create library.

After that i add this library in my current app (name UseLabProject).so follow the same path asa baove and after click `add` button and add mainLabProject  as library in my current Apps.

also apply the permission  in my current app`s maniFest file Like.

**`<uses-library android:name="info.main" android:required="true" />`**

but when i run this apps this type error occur in conesole

```
2012-07-21 12:18:05 - UseLabProject] Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY
[2012-07-21 12:18:05 - UseLabProject] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2012-07-21 12:18:05 - UseLabProject] Launch canceled!
```

and This type error in Logcat

```
07-21 12:18:04.172: ERROR/PackageManager(63): Package info.use requires unavailable shared library info.main.MainLabProject; failing!
```

so now i how to solve this problem.

i remove the permission from manifest file then got this type exception

```
07-21 12:56:23.885: E/AndroidRuntime(4663): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{info.use/info.use.UseLabProject}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {info.use/info.main.MainLabProject}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `<uses-library android:name="info.main" android:required="true" />` in your manifest. Remove it and try, if won't help try to clean your lib and project.

Comment: i do this but info.main.MainLabProjectActivity can`t access in my current app.Display this type error in console           [2012-07-21 12:31:41 - MainLabProject] Could not find MainLabProject.apk!

Comment: You want to access activity from a library in your project? If so, read this http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html, section Declaring library components in the manifest file.

Comment: Also check if you have your library in Java Build Path, Libraries path, Android Dependencies tree.

Comment: i check all path but not give proper solution

Comment: Create simple empty class in your lib and try to use it in your project. If that works than from docs "In the manifest file of the application project, you must add declarations of all components that the application will use that are imported from a library project. For example, you must declare any <activity>, <service>, <receiver>, <provider>, and so on, as well as <permission>, <uses-library>, and similar elements. Declarations should reference the library components by their fully-qualified package names, where appropriate." Have you declared your activities from lib in app' manifest?